# Arduino looping in switch case until button pressed again

Tags: loops, arduino, switch-statement, case

I am having issues with this part of the code. What I would like to happen is that when I press IR button 0xFF629D, I would like it to run forever unless I press the same button again. What I am trying to do is if the value of voltage is > 0.30 , the relay will turn on. After, it will continue looping until I want to exit the case by pressing the same button.

Is this possible to do?

I will not copy the entire code but this is the switch case part:

```
    void translateIR() // takes action based on IR code received

{

  switch(results.value)

  {

  case 0xFFA25D:
    Serial.println(" TOGGLE RELAY ON            ");
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);  
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);
    break;


  case 0xFFE21D:
    Serial.println(" 1h30            ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);
  }
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);    
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  Serial.println(" RELAY ON");     
  delay(10000);           //1h30
  Serial.println(" RELAY OFF");
  digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);
  break;

  case 0xFF22DD:
    Serial.println(" 12h           ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);

  }
  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  Serial.println(" RELAY ON");     
  delay(10000);           //12 hour
  Serial.println(" RELAY OFF");  
      digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);
    break;

  case 0xFF02FD:
    Serial.println(" TOGGLE RELAY OFF           ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(250);                       // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(250);
  }
     digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
     digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);
    break;



  case 0xFF629D: 

    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);

    Serial.println(" Automatic mode            ");   

  digitalWrite(LEDACT, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)

  if (voltage > 0.30) {
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  Serial.println(" RELAY ON");
  delay(1000); 
  digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
  Serial.println(" RELAY OFF");
    digitalWrite(LEDACT, LOW);

}
    break;

  default:
    Serial.println(" other button   ");

  }
```

Comment: Just check your button state again in every loop cycle and break the loop if the button is pressed a second time. What is your problem here?

Comment: I have heard of button states before but I don't know how I can implement it. Would it mean I have a break; within the loop? Is there example code I can look for?

Comment: you get this `0xFF629D` somehow. so you should know how to find out if the button is pressed. just do it again in the loop waiting for the second button press.

Comment: This is the IR code from a remote I have found. How would I implement a second button press in the loop? Would it be something like while(key pressed) do something forever else if (key pressed again) break. Would that make sense? How would you do it with me code?

Comment: like you impelmented the first one? I mean you already did it once. why can't you do it a second time?

Comment: Yes but when I press for the first time it goes through the case and then returns back to the switch meny. So in order to start again I need to press the button again. I would like to press it once and it loops forever until I press the button again and then returns back to the switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201546/discussion-between-m2t156-and-piglet).